# csrf token per page - java.lang.IllegalStateException: must define 'uri' attribute when token per page is enabled

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, csrf, csrf-token

I am trying to enable the token par page from CsrfGuard.properties. but after deploying while I am trying to access the URL I am getting a 500 error because it's throwing below exception.

Can you please help me to fix this? Where do I need to pass/define this URI?

**CsrfGuard.properties**

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPagePrecreated=true
```

**JSP Page:**

```
<form name="test">
.....
     <input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>" value="<csrf:token-value/>"/>
</form>
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: must define 'uri' attribute when token per page is enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need to be added part of token value t tag,

```
<input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>" value="<csrf:token-value uri='page.jsp' />"/>
```